# Tizen native project creating fail by Tizen Studio CLI on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, command-line-interface, tizen

I want to create native project by Tizen Studio CLI on Unbuntu 16.04 according to below official guide.

[Command Line Interface Commands](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tizen-studio/web-tools/cli)

I tried below command but CLI returned error message.

```
$tizen create native-project -p mobile-5.0 -t basic-ui -n basic2 -- ~/workspace
An error has occurred. See the log file tizen-sdk/tools/ide/cli.log.
```

I found cli.log as below.

```
2019-08-06 15:32:12,519 [TRACE] Main.java(131) - Start running Tizen CLI Main class...
2019-08-06 15:32:12,520 [TRACE] Main.java(132) - Argument count:12
2019-08-06 15:32:12,530 [TRACE] CreateCLI.java(37) - execute Create cli...
2019-08-06 15:32:12,628 [ERROR] AbstractCLI.java(93) - Failed to create native project
org.tizen.ncli.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Failed to create native project
        at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.createnative.CreateNativeProjectCommand.call(CreateNativeProjectCommand.java:101)
        at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.createnative.CreateNativeProjectCommand.call(CreateNativeProjectCommand.java:66)
        at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.AbstractSubCommand.runCommand(AbstractSubCommand.java:76)
        at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.CreateNativeProjectCLI.execute(CreateNativeProjectCLI.java:92)
        at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.CreateCLI.execute(CreateCLI.java:40)
        at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.AbstractCLI.execute(AbstractCLI.java:91)
        at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.Main.run(Main.java:187)
        at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.Main.main(Main.java:119)
2019-08-06 15:32:23,171 [TRACE] Main.java(131) - Start running Tizen CLI Main class...
2019-08-06 15:32:23,173 [TRACE] Main.java(132) - Argument count:12
2019-08-06 15:32:23,182 [TRACE] CreateCLI.java(37) - execute Create cli...
2019-08-06 15:32:23,462 [ERROR] AbstractCLI.java(93) -
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.tizen.nativecommon.templateengine.build.BuildPluginManagerForCLI.getDevPackageModel(BuildPluginManagerForCLI.java:399)
        at org.tizen.nativecommon.templateengine.TizenTemplateEngine.getDevPackageModels(TizenTemplateEngine.java:245)
        at org.tizen.nativecommon.templateengine.TizenTemplateEngine.createProject(TizenTemplateEngine.java:134)
        at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.createnative.CreateNativeProjectCommand.copyNativeProjectTemplate(CreateNativeProjectCommand.java:195)
        at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.createnative.CreateNativeProjectCommand.call(CreateNativeProjectCommand.java:99)
        at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.createnative.CreateNativeProjectCommand.call(CreateNativeProjectCommand.java:66)
        at org.tizen.ncli.subcommands.AbstractSubCommand.runCommand(AbstractSubCommand.java:76)
        at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.CreateNativeProjectCLI.execute(CreateNativeProjectCLI.java:92)
        at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.CreateCLI.execute(CreateCLI.java:40)
        at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.AbstractCLI.execute(AbstractCLI.java:91)
        at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.Main.run(Main.java:187)
        at org.tizen.ncli.ide.shell.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

It is a simple first step for development of Tizen Application but I can't do that. **What can I do to solve this issue?** I already tried to re-install Tizen-Studio and SDK. Is there anything I can try to do?

My java version is as below.

```
$java -version
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed "platformIDE" in Tizen SDK tools, this kind of issue can be found. 
Could you uninstall "platformIDE" and  try again?
We'll look into it and update the results.

Thank you for reporting the issue.

Comment: After delete "platformIDE" by package manager, it work well. But I don't know how it work.